# how many incarnations of the master have there been and the confirmed only faces

Tags: doctor-who, regeneration

In *Doctor Who* they have said the Master has used up regenerations and started stealing bodies but the only Masters we see on screen are

[image]

How many Masters have we not seen? Are theses the only and true Masters in a regenerative cycle and are these the confirmed incarnations of the master?

Comment: Read my answer to that question; I don't see a distinction between the two questions, and my answer seems to cover everything you're asking for about the Master's incarnations